# How can I merge my friend's new phone number in WhatsApp without losing all the chats history (merge chats from two different numbers to one number)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, chat

I've been using WhatsApp with my best friend for years and he swapped his prepaid simcard (old phone with with number = X) with a new prepaid simcard (new phone with number Y) recently.
When he sent me the first message using the new phone with number Y, I received a new chat window because his number Y was not registered on my phone contact's list.
When getting this new chat, I blocked the number because it was unknown to me.
When he gave his new number Y, I added it to his contact record on my phone but chats didn't merge together and this is not what I had expected, because now I have our two separate chats: the old one and the new one.

How can I merge the 2 chat windows together and keep only the one with the whole chat/calls/medias history?

Thank you,
Bruno

Summary : Is there any way to Merge two different WhatsApp chats into one single chat ?
Practical issue being someone used two different numbers to text.

Comment: You can't. Accounts are mapped to numbers. I have heard of rooted means to achieve this but not always successful